# Find points of discontinuity of $x(x-1)^{2/3}e^{\sqrt[3]{x}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to find the points of discontinuity for the following function:

$$f(x)=x(x-1)^{2/3}e^{\sqrt[3]{x}}$$

My textbook says it can be derived for every number except $0$ and $1$ which could be points of discontinuity. I have no idea how it reached that conclusion without deriving the function first.  Now, I find the first derivative by using the product rule:

$$f'(x)=e^{\sqrt[3]{x}}\left[{\frac {x^{4/3}-x^{1/3}+5x-3}{3(x-1)^{1/3}}}\right]$$

My textbook asks for the domain. I know that $\sqrt[3]{x}$ are defined for any $x$ so I focus on the denominator which should not be equal to $0$, therefore $3(x-1)^{1/3}\neq0\implies x-1\neq0\implies x \neq 1$. Wolfram Alpha [says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Bderivative%20of%20x(x-1)%5E(2%2F3)e%5E(x%5E(1%2F3))%5D%20domain) the domain should be $x>1$.

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The non-differentiable points could be spotted via the fraction in the definition of derivatives.

Comment: @xbh $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}$ you mean by replacing, e.g. $f(x) =x$ (which is a term of the product of the function)?

Comment: Probably… I am not sure what you mean… I was saying that you could verify the fact by directly computing the limit in the definition.

Comment: As for domain, see [Rational powers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Power_functions). Then $(x-1)^{2/3}$ is defined only for $x >1$.

Comment: However for $2/3$-power, $x <0$ would not cause any ambiguity in set of real numbers. So you might be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability Wolfram assumes $(x-1)^{2/3}$ defined only for $x-1\ge 0\implies x\ge 1$.

Comment: Thanks this is correct, now I need to investigate why. I thought that $(x-1)^{2/3}=\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}$ would always be defined

Comment: I agree there is something unclear, as anyway the cubic root is defined everywhere in $\Bbb R$, so $(\sqrt[3]{x-1})^2$ has $\Bbb R$ as domain as well.

Comment: No idea what's going on. Very unclear (Wolfram not the answer).

Comment: @Cesare It is solely a matter of definition $x^{2/3}$ is well defined for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ but in general $x^{m/n}$ is not therefore in general the limitation $x\ge 0$ is assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Wolfram assumes $(x−1)^{2/3}$ has abranch cut in $x=1$